# SQL concat two columns into one

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, concatenation

Using SQL, I would like to concat two columns into one.

Here the input table consisting of two columns:

```
stop_id         stop_sequence
--------        -------------
35792956        1
29923564        5
64392834        3
54832139        71
98323521        25
73410935        4
```

Desired output

```
stop_id_coded
-------------
 357929561
 299235645
 643928343
5483213971
9832352125
 734109354
```

Notice: all data is TEXT in this case.

Here my trials:

Trial 1:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_result_table AS
  SELECT DISTINCT STR(stop_id + stop_sequence) as stop_id_coded
  FROM my_input_table;
```

Error: no such function: STR

Trial 2:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_result_table AS
  SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(stop_id + stop_sequence) as stop_id_coded
  FROM my_input_table;
```

Error: no such function: CONCAT

Trial 3:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_result_table AS
  SELECT DISTINCT (stop_id + stop_sequence) as stop_id_coded
  FROM my_input_table;
```

No error - but the resulting `stop_id_coded` columns still only consists of `stop_id` column (and `stop_sequence` seems ignored for some unknown reason....)

Any help on this appreciated ?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: [Apparently](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-string-functions/sqlite-concat/) the concatenation operator for dbbrowser is `||` (this wasn't hard to find, did you search?)

Comment: Thanks HoneyBadger, I wasn't aware that SQL and SQLite use different syntax. And since this all pretty new to me I was on the wrong track. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below code ..

```
CREATE TABLE my_result_table AS
    SELECT DISTINCT stop_id || stop_sequence AS stop_id_coded
    FROM my_input_table
```

If above code is not working then try below one ..

```
CREATE TABLE my_result_table AS
    SELECT DISTINCT cast(stop_id as VARCHAR(100)) || cast(stop_sequence as VARCHAR(100)) AS stop_id_coded
    FROM my_input_table
```

Comment: Bro, use || operator instead of CONCAT, SQLLite does'nt support concat  function

Answer (score 1):

Please try following,

```
CREATE TABLE my_result_table AS    
SELECT (stop_id  || stop_sequence) AS stop_id_coded
FROM my_input_table;
```

Comment: Kush, thank you - your solution is working as well !! (or as stated, Ajeet's solution as well).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE my_result_table AS    
SELECT CONCAT(stop_id  , stop_sequence) AS stop_id_coded
FROM my_input_table;
```

Comment: always give detail answer so that other users will understand your solution more.